# amcl does not need odometry data?

Tags: navigation, odometry, position, localilzation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm reading [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) document on ROS Wiki. In its subscribed topics there is not odometry topic, why? It works only with laser?

```
**Subscribed Topics:**

scan (sensor_msgs/LaserScan)
tf (tf/tfMessage)
initialpose (geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped)
map (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98221/amcl-does-not-need-odometry-data?/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

amcl receives its odometry informations through the `/odom` -> `/base_link` transform. (Or whatever you have set as `odom_frame_id` and `base_frame_id` parameters)

This means that you need a node (typically your hardware abstraction) that accumulates odom information from your base-robot and publish the aggregated pose as a transform.

So no, laser only will not be sufficient.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3